# count_documents gives error: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_txn_read_preference'

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I wrote a function to check if a row exists, then insert if it is not there, or update if it is there. So I'm trying to use `count_documents`. I'm using a field called `filetype` as my unique key.

A sample document looks like this:

```json
{
    "_id": ObjectId("652d47a64732d257ee31e846"),
    "filetype": "USTreasuryBillRates",
    "last_date_processed": "2023-10-16T00:00:00.000Z",
    "update_date": "2023-10-16T10:13:45.000Z"
}
```

Python function:

```
def upsert_load_history(arg_file_type, arg_date, arg_db_collection):
    # insert if not there, otherwise update in place
    print("===== upsert_load_history ======")

    json_query = {"filetype": arg_file_type}
    row_count = arg_db_collection.count_documents(json_query, {'limit': 1})
    if row_count == 0:
        insert_load_history_new_rows(arg_file_type, arg_date, arg_db_collection)
    else:
        update_load_history_for_file_type(arg_file_type, arg_date, arg_db_collection)
```

Error:

```
===== upsert_load_history ======
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\GitHub\ClientName\Apps\LambdaUSTreasury\SetupLoadHistoryDB.py", line 134, in <module>
    upsert_load_history(file_type, file_date, db_collection_filehistory)
  File "C:\GitHub\ClientName\Apps\LambdaUSTreasury\SetupLoadHistoryDB.py", line 61, in upsert_load_history
    row_count = arg_db_collection.count_documents(json_query, {'limit': 1})
  File "C:\GitHub\ClientName\Apps\LambdaUSTreasury\pymongo\collection.py", line 1786, in count_documents
    _cmd, self._read_preference_for(session), session)
  File "C:\GitHub\ClientName\Apps\LambdaUSTreasury\pymongo\common.py", line 870, in _read_preference_for
    return session._txn_read_preference() or self.__read_preference
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_txn_read_preference'
```

Comment: The second positional argument to [`count_documents`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.count_documents) should be a _session_, not a dictionary. Either unpack the dictionary to kwargs, or just explicitly set `limit=1`.

Comment: Consider using `update_one` or `replace_one` which both support `upsert=True`, which can perform an upsert in a single operation.

Comment: @BellyBuster - That's exactly what I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on JonRSharpe's comment, this is my corrected code.
Basically changed {'limit':1} to limit=1.

```
def upsert_load_history(arg_file_type, arg_date, arg_db_collection):
    # insert if not there, otherwise update in place
    print("===== upsert_load_history ======")
    update_date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z")

    json_query = {"filetype": arg_file_type}
    row_count = arg_db_collection.count_documents(json_query, limit=1)
    if row_count == 0:
        insert_load_history_new_rows(arg_file_type, arg_date, arg_db_collection)
    else:
        update_load_history_for_file_type(arg_file_type, arg_date, arg_db_collection)
```

Also, per Belly Buster's comment, I had already discovered the "Upsert" functionality. Below I coded a new method to test it and it worked fine.  Added the "upsert=True" parameter to the call to the update_one method. It will insert if not exists, and update if exists.

```
def update2_load_history_for_file_type(arg_file_type, arg_date, arg_db_collection):
    # do update without retrieve first, using the upsert feature
    print("===== update_load_history_for_file_type ======")

    # Note, in my collection, filetype is my unique key 
    json_query = {'filetype': arg_file_type}

    update_date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z")
    json_update = {
         '$set': {
            'last_date_processed': arg_date,
            'update_date': update_date
         }
         }

    print("json_query:")
    pprint.pprint(json_query)
    print("json_update:")
    pprint.pprint(json_update)
    result = arg_db_collection.update_one(json_query, json_update, upsert=True)
    print("Update result.matched_count=", result.matched_count)
```